# Swift Combine: `sink` works with model.$name but not with model.name.publisher. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the a model with a published name property:

```
@MainActor class MyModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var name = ""

    ....

}
```

I am wondering why sink works when used on `model.$name` and not on `model.name.publisher`.

```
model.$name
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { name in
        ....            <-- it's called. works.
    }
    .store(in: &subs)
```

This does not get called:

```
model.name.publisher
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { name in
        ....            <-- does not get called.
    }
    .store(in: &subs)
```

Can someone explain exactly why I have to use the `$` sign in front of name and why `name.publisher` does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$name` is how you access the underlying `Publisher` of the `@Published` property wrapper.
This publisher will emit every time the `name` property mutates and probably that's what you want.

With `model.name.publisher` you get a `Publisher` that will emit each character of the `String` and then complete (It's defined on a `Sequence` extension)
If you have:

```
@MainActor class MyModel:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var name = "foo"

    ....

}
```

You will see `f - o - o`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I understand why it's confusing.

`$name` refers to the publisher within the `@Published` property-wrapper. It is what you want.

`name.publisher` is something within String. Fabio Felici's answer explains it well. It will cycle through characters (it returns `String.Element`) of the current string, rather than new values of the string when it is swapped out. For that, use `$name`. (on which `sink` returns a `String` type for each change.)